# Congratulation Joan for 50k!

Tags: discussion

Congratulation to Joan for being the first user on RaspberryPi to reach the astonishing amount of 50k rep.

Thanks for putting in that much effort (close to 2k answers) to help countless (stats say "~4.1m people reached" and I hope they mean "M" not "m" by this) users to get along with their Raspberry Pi. I hope you keep sticking around posting high quality answers, not to mention being an example for others to follow.

Comment: @joan: I'd like to add my congratulations. Over 2,000 answers!! I can't even imagine...  And that doesn't even count the answers you provided on "that other Raspberry Pi website" :) I would like you to know your efforts are sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, they are much appreciated!

Comment: Congratulations! Excellent work @joan

Comment: 50k in five years!

Comment: @joan Well done!